# User login/session system description

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra

I'm building my first web app, and I've got all these crazy ideas on ways I could handle things like logins/sessions, but I was wondering if anyone has written a really good, thorough description of how logins/sessions work. I've seen tutorials, but I want to know if theres something more abstract that gives the reader a more general idea of how the whole process is handled. My web app is in ruby/sinatra if that's relevant.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the in-depth tutorials for login/authentication from scratch are for Rails unfortunately. I went through the same trouble trying to find Sinatra specific tutorials. I would recommend just checking out the rails oriented tutorials since the knowledge is pretty general and can be applied to Sinatra as well.

These guides from RailsGuides are pretty good for getting an understanding of authentication even though they are Rails specific (read the section on security especially):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Here's an example of a good Sinatra authentication scheme on github (it uses the datamapper gem, but you can easily replace this with any other Ruby [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)):

https://github.com/daddz/sinatra-dm-login

If you aren't as interested in rolling your own, you can also try the sinatra-authentication gem:

https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication